# Unable to call new intent using Handler

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to android. I have used handler to run timer in my code. I was trying to make a timer which calls a new intent when time is less than zero or it is negative. This program is giving Runtime errors. I tried with 0L in if condition. But program doesnt work. If i use 0 instead of 0L in if condition then the value timeToGo continue to decrease in negative. There is no error in Game.java as it has default android page. i think there is a different way to call intent in handler. Please help to solve this problem. Thank you

The activity_main file is as follows

```
package com.example.test;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tt1;
    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L,timeToGo=0L,startTime=0L;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
    }
    public Runnable updateTimerThread=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
            timeToGo = 30 - (timeNow - startTime) / 1000;
            tt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tt1.setText(timeToGo+"");
            if(timeToGo<0L){
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Game.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
                }

            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };

 }
```

Comment: maybe the stacktrace of the crash would help. Add `customHandler.removeCallbacks(null); return;` just after `startActivity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you have to call startActivity() on the application's main thread. And not from the background thread. To do so change your handler:

```
  private  Handler customHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Comment: After using this the intent works but the application hangs and force closes after some time.

Comment: There might be another issue with Activity that you are launching. I can't give you an answer for that, as I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I mean that the new Activity doesnt open proplerly and activity called is default hello world.

Comment: Remove the finish() from the runnable. Is it ok now?

Comment: Can you add the  customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0); from the run() in an else statement? I.e. if(timeToGo<0L){ ...}else{customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);}

Comment: @NimitAggarwal You are welcome! Can you accept the answer then?